# Webbrowser windows phone don't show an image

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application, i'm using a webbrowser to render a HTML like this

```
private void webBrowserHTML_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser web = sender as WebBrowser;
        string description = web.DataContext.ToString();
        web.NavigateToString(description);
    }
```

My problem is i have html code that show an image in the variable `description`:

```
<a href=\"tel:3950\"><img width=\"220\" class=\"logo\" alt=\"3950\" src=\"bandeau3950.png\" /> </a>
```

I put the image in the same folder with my code, but the image is not shown in the application.

[image]

Any solution please?

Comment: How did you solve this ? i am also facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

Use Base64 image uri format so that image is defined as part of html. You can use online conversion tools, like http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter

Solution 2

1. Copy all required images to isolated storage folder. It can be done during app start up.
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811%28VS.92%29.aspx
2. When html string is received save it to the same isolated storage as index.html
3. Do Navigate(new Uri("folder/index.html", UriKind.Relative))

In this case browser will be able to show images since your page and images in the same isolated storage folder.